# How to build table upon nested json file

Tags: json, apache-spark, amazon-athena

I have a json file which contains information about my spark job running on EMR, I wanted to build  athena table on the top of it. I ran glue crawler and was trying to make a table but it was giving error due to my json being nested.

My json file looks like :

```json
{
    "Report_for": "Reconciliation",
    "Execution_of": "application_1673496470638_0001",
    "Spark_version": "2.4.7-amzn-0",
    "Java_version": "1.8.0_352 (Amazon.com Inc.)",
    "Start_time": "2023-01-12 09:45:13.360000",
    "Job_ID 0": {
        "Submission_time": "2023-01-12 09:47:20.148000",
        "Run_time": "73957ms",
        "Result": "JobSucceeded",
        "Number_of_stages": "1",
        "Stage_ID 0": {
            "Number_of_tasks": "16907",
            "Number_of_executed_tasks": "16907",
            "Completion_time": "73207ms",
            "Stage_executed": "parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53"
        }
    },
    "Job_ID 1": {
        "Submission_time": "2023-01-12 09:48:34.177000",
        "Run_time": "11525ms",
        "Result": "JobSucceeded",
        "Number_of_stages": "2",
        "Stage_ID 1": {
            "Number_of_tasks": "16907",
            "Number_of_executed_tasks": "0",
            "Completion_time": "0ms",
            "Stage_executed": "parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53"
        },
        "Stage_ID 2": {
            "Number_of_tasks": "300",
            "Number_of_executed_tasks": "300",
            "Completion_time": "11520ms",
            "Stage_executed": "parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53"
        }
    },
    "Job_ID 2": {
        "Submission_time": "2023-01-12 09:48:46.908000",
        "Run_time": "218358ms",
        "Result": "JobSucceeded",
        "Number_of_stages": "1",
        "Stage_ID 3": {
            "Number_of_tasks": "1135",
            "Number_of_executed_tasks": "1135",
            "Completion_time": "218299ms",
            "Stage_executed": "parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53"
        }
    },
    "Job_ID 3": {
        "Submission_time": "2023-01-12 09:52:25.313000",
        "Run_time": "7503ms",
        "Result": "JobSucceeded",
        "Number_of_stages": "2",
        "Stage_ID 5": {
            "Number_of_tasks": "300",
            "Number_of_executed_tasks": "300",
            "Completion_time": "7502ms",
            "Stage_executed": "parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53"
        },
        "Stage_ID 4": {
            "Number_of_tasks": "1135",
            "Number_of_executed_tasks": "0",
            "Completion_time": "0ms",
            "Stage_executed": "parquet at RawDataPublisher.scala:53"
        }
    },
}
```

I tried flattening my json using [this aws post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/simplify-querying-nested-json-with-the-aws-glue-relationalize-transform/), but it was complex to implement.

I also tried creating table on athena with [this aws post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/create-tables-in-amazon-athena-from-nested-json-and-mappings-using-jsonserde/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20create%20tables%20by,data). But was not sure of the columns.

Is there another way I could build a table or dashboard upon my json file.